ReactJS Node and lighttpd
I am just starting with React and its frameworks. I need to develop an UI for an embedded device. The device is running linux with lighttpd as webserver (no Node available).
What it's not really clear to me at the moment, it is whether or not do I need Node installed on the device to serve a React WEB UI developed with Next.js.
I know that with next.js I can "export" the UI, after building it, as a SSG (Static Site Generation).
In such a case the equivalent .html files of the WEB UI will be available in the output folder.
Is that correct ?
Moreover I'm not sure if I just need to put these files in the webserver's root folder to serve them as a "classic" html/css/js UI.
Can anyone better clarify me that ?
thanks !

Generally Next.js implies server-side rendering, which precludes the non-presence of Node. You can use plain React whose output is a plain static html/js/css files, that can be served by any normal webserver.

Hello @Alejandro, thanks for you reply ! Now it's more clear. From the official react website it seems that for building an app i need to choose a framework:
"Build the React part of your app using one of the React-based frameworks."

The suggested frameworks are: Next.js (seems the one to be preferred), remix, gatsby and expo.
So I'm still a little confused
